# PHP GET добавление значения в ссылку

Tags: php, html, post, get, input

Добрый день!

Файл order.php (прикрепляю код ниже) подсасывает данные из html и передает их на почту (имя, телефон, адрес и прочее). Далее, после отправки данных на почту скрипт перекидывает человека на другую страницу html.

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы перекидывала не на страницу *"/success_order1.html"*, а на страницу *"/success_order1.html?+'.@$_POST['name'].'"* и открывалась страница с URL типа: *"/success_order1.html?Игорь"* ?

```html
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
exit;

$email = "xxxxxx@bk.ru";
$title = "Новый заказ. xxxxxxxx";
$from = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$text = 'Информация о заказе:

Товар: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (http://xxxxxxxx/mob1/)
Имя: '.@$_POST['name'].'
Телефон: '.@$_POST['phone'].'
Адрес: '.@$_POST['address'].'
Время заказа: '.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'

Метки:
utm_source: '.@$_POST['utm_source'].'
utm_medium: '.@$_POST['utm_medium'].'
utm_campaign: '.@$_POST['utm_campaign'].'
utm_content: '.@$_POST['utm_content'].'
utm_term: '.@$_POST['utm_term'].'';
if(mail($email, $title, $text, "Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$from"))
echo 
"<html><head><title>Спасибо за заказ!</title></head><body><div style='margin: 150px auto; width: 300px;'></div></body></html>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=./success_order1.html' />";
else
echo "<h2>Ошибка! Попробуйте ещё раз!</h2>";
?>
```

Comment: У вас тут ошибка. Meta refresh, должен в Head быть.

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov ну это по сути не важно, т.к. скрипт моментально перекидывает с изначального HTML на /success_order1.html

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился заменой УРЛ на:

```html
 url=./success_order1.html?name=" .  $_POST['name']  . "
```

Comment: Желательно добавить какой-нибудь `urlencode`